# Safari is not showing style sheets

Tags: safari, safari-extensions, formatting

For some reason, starting yesterday, Safari will not show ANY style sheets for any webpage I visit.  I updated today to Safari 5.0.5 thinking that might help, but it didn't.

I restarted, and that didn't help either.  Here's an example of what it looks like:

[image: image1]

I am not running extensions or any custom style sheets.  I did notice something odd with the extensions section of the safari preferences:

[image: image2]

Any ideas / suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You could try recreating your Safari Preferences plist:

1. Quit Safari.
2. Open Finder -> Library -> Preferences
3. Move com.apple.Safari.plist to your Desktop.
4. Open Safari.

Comment: Glad I could help!